# Multiple connections on one BLE beacon

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have a single BLE beacon and I try to connect to it with multiple Android phones in order to get the RSSI, and see who is the closest to it.
But, just after the first phone connect to the beacon (via a BluetoothGatt), the beacon never appears from the scan again in the scan results of the other phones, so they cannot connect to it too.
The only solution I see is to scan without connection and get the RSSI from the scan result, but I don't think that is an elegant solution.
Is there a way to have multiple connection to a single BLE beacon and get the RSSI ?

Thank you

Comment: That is the only correct solution - use RSSI from advertisement packets.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the BLE device to decide if it supports more than one connection. If it only wants to support one connection, it can be programmed to stop advertising when a connection is established. From a client perspective, there's not much you can do about that. If you can modify the firmware in the beacon, you can add support for multiple connections.

Otherwise there is nothing wrong with using the rssi in the advertising packet (although you can't make use of BLE security (pairing / bonding)).